# How do you check if a string contains abc?

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool s = StringMethod("aBc");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    public static Boolean StringMethod(String s)
    {

        if (s.ToUpper() != "abc".ToUpper() && s == " ")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        return true;
    }
```

---

The method must answer true if the receiving text includes "abc" or "ABC" or AbC" (Upper or Lower Case not important) and false otherwise.

Ex: The method receive "foabc". It answer  true.

Ex: The method receive "iABCc". It answer true.

Ex: The method receive "aBCd". It answer  true.

Ex: The method receive "aBdc". It answer  false.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at your condition of `&& s == " "`. You're basically saying that `s` *has* to be a single space. In what way should "foabc" return true?

Comment: I know, what can i do to put any a string before or after the string "abc"?, im sorry for asking such questions, but im kinda new to this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing strings with other than a literal comparison, consider using overloads of the [string class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.aspx) that take a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) value or using a [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) to avoid creating unnecessary strings.

In your case, what you are looking for is something like this:

```
public static bool StringMethod(string s)
{
    return s.IndexOf("abc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```